# Identifying original elements in a permutation of a pattern

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, maximum-likelihood, pattern-recognition

[image: Pattern Example]

In the pattern above, the blue peaks are known and are labeled $p_1, p_2, ... p_N$. The red line is the same pattern of peaks, but altered slightly. Given a blue pattern and red pattern, I want to be able to identify which red peaks correspond to $p_1, p_2, ... p_N$ in the blue pattern.

Note that in the example $p_6$ and $p_7$ are missing in the red pattern. It is possible in my data for peaks to be missing and for extra peaks to appear. Thankfully, order is preserved among the existing peaks. (A red $p_1$ will never appear after a red $p_2$). An extra peak could appear between them though.

Currently I'm trying to line up the array of red peaks against the array of blue peaks so that the height deviation and position deviation is the smallest among corresponding elements. This is unreliable when the red peaks are heavily shifted on the horizontal axis. It is also thrown off by missing peaks and extra peaks.

I'm hoping there is a clustering algorithm of some sort that can detect the best matching peaks.

Edit: I should probably mention that the data looks like:

```py
bluePeaks = [{'height': 100, 'position': 20}, ...]
redPeaks = [{'height': 105, 'position': 21}, ...]
result = [{'height': 105, 'position': 21, 'id': 0}, ...]
```

Comment: Consider looking into a version of an "edit distance" rather than clustering techniques.  [Dynamic Time Warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) also looks like a promising approach.